# Pentagon Chart in PHP

Tags: php, cakephp, charts, google-visualization, cakephp-2.1

I want to implement a pentagonal shaped chart according to my historical data saved in database in PHP. In fact I want to use it in CakePHP. 
Need yours help either by providing any chart api link or any library available online.
Thanks in advance.

[image: The chart should somehow looks like it]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called radar charts, not pentagonal charts.

You can use this Javascript library: http://www.amcharts.com/javascript/radar-chart/

Or use the pChart PHP library: http://pchart.sourceforge.net/documentation.php?topic=exemple8

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. I was supposed to find through Pentagonal term.

Comment: The library given in your second link is using Java. I need it in PHP.

Comment: Look again!?!? It says "a PHP Class to build Charts" and the example code is clearly PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily (or advanced) with [JPGraph](http://jpgraph.net/features/gallery.php#rader1). The library is free for non-commercial, open-source or educational use. An example on how to setup a radar graph with it can be found [here](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch16s02.html).